# How to increase only last three digits of a serial number string in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a button in excel that will add a new serial number to the next available line. The serial number will be DC001 and the next DC002 and so on... The code will need to look at the last 3 digits on the serial number and increase by one, then add this number to the next available row. I cant seem to be able to do this with the DC in front of the number. Is anyone able to help please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Magical Mystery Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the `VBA` code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Even recording a macro is a way to start.

Answer (score 1):

In the excel worksheet use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & TEXT(INT(RIGHT(A1,3)) + 1, "000")
```

*Explanation*:

The result will be the *concatenation* (`&`) of your original 2-character prefix (`LEFT(A1,2)`) and the original number (`INT(RIGHT(A1,3))`) increased by `1` and converted to text (`TEXT`) with 3-digits (`"000"`)

Or use its equivalent in VBA:

```
Left(Your_variable, 2) & Format(Int(Right(Your_variable, 3)) + 1, "000")
```

as the code for your button.

See [Add a button and assign a macro to it in a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)  if you have problem how to use this VBA formula.